# Highcharts datalabel for each stacked column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've produced the following chart using HighCharts:

[image]

Where the red numbers above each column are pulled from the series data for each quarter. I've used dataLabels with custom data to achieve this:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Q1',
            'Q2',
            'Q3',
            'Q4'
        ],
        title: {
            text: 'Year Quarter',
            margin: 20,
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontWeight: '600'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'No. Incidents',
            margin: 20,
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontWeight: '600'
            }
        },
        labels: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'left',
                crop: false,
                style: {
                    color: '#ff0000',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.series.options.cost
                },
                y: -20,
                x: 0,
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        "name": "Plant",
        "data": [11,34,24,11],
        "cost": 23
    },
    {
        "name": "Ship",
        "data": [23,13,15,24],
        "cost": 34,
        "dataLabels": {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Equipment",
        "data": [23,16,24,42],
        "cost": 33,
        "dataLabels": {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Cargo",
        "data": [23,34,33,24],
        "cost": 24,
        "dataLabels": {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
}
```

However as you can see it shows 23 for all columns instead of the cost for each individual series. I've also disabled the datalabels for the other 3 series as otherwise it puts the datalabels on each stack rather than each column.

How can I show the correct cost for each column as per my screenshot?

Comment: The reason of that is you disable datalabels for other series, so each time iterate on each point from first serie, value is returned. Better is using [stacklabels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels.formatter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels for stacks can be set through yAxis and are called [`stackLabels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels).

```
    ...
    yAxis: [{
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            style: {
                color: '#ff0000',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            x: -5,
            verticalAlign: 'top'
        }
    ...
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8e08b387/1/